# extracting the post parameters from a form using javascript/jQuery before submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how can i get the parameters of any form being submitted with method=post before it's submitted using javascript(preferably jQuery).
What i am trying to do is get the post parameters and submit it to an alternate loacation.
 i was using

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert('action=  ' + $(this).attr("action"));
  alert('serialized string' + $(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

but it works only with get request i want to extract the parameters from the post requests too .

Comment: Serialization should have nothing to do with what type of method the form uses to make the request.  I use `serialize` with forms that POST all the time.  Perhaps you have something else that's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works for me

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
        $.post(your_location, $(this).serialize());
    return false;
  });
```

You can use the any other Ajax method you like if you don't want to use $.post(). You can also include a callback method to handle whatever your ajax call returns.